# Query to compare if row value it's the same from a row before

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to compare if a row value it's the same as the value before this, considering it's ordered by a Policy and update a column from the same table when this is the case.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

This table is ordered by Policy and the column 'Equals' has NULL as values (*table 1*), so I want it to update it so if the value in the column 'Import' it's the same as the value in the column 'Import' from the row before this.

If that is the case then the value on the column 'Equals' would update to 'Yes' otherwise it would be 'No' (*table 2*).

Table 1:

```
Policy  Import  Equals
------  ------  ------
0001    2045.4   null
0001    1024.7   null
0002     111.0   null
0003     111.0   null
0006    2045.4   null
0008    1111.5   null
0008     123.4   null
0008     123.4   null
0010    9999.9   null
0120     123.4   null
```

Table 2:

```
Policy  Import  Equals
------  ------  ------
0001    2045.4   no
0001    1024.7   no
0002     111.0   yes
0003     111.0   yes
0006    2045.4   no
0008    1111.5   no
0008     123.4   yes
0008     123.4   yes
0010    9999.9   no
0120     123.4   no
```

Here's the SQL Code to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
  Policy varchar(20),
  Import Decimal(15,2),
  Equals varchar(6)
)

INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0001',2045.4,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0001',1024.7,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0002',111.0,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0003',111.0,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0006',2045.4,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0008',1111.5,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0008',123.4,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0008',123.4,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0010',9999.9,null)
INSERT INTO Example VALUES('0120',123.4,null)
```

And here's what I've been trying without success:

```
WITH temp 
AS (
  SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Policy) as rowNumber
  FROM Example c
)
SELECT
x.*
FROM temp x
WHERE x.Import = (SELECT y.Import FROM temp y WHERE y.rowNumber = x.rowNumber - 1)
```

Expected result:

```
Policy  Import  Equals  rowNumber
0002    111.0   NULL    3
0003    111.0   NULL    4
0008    123.4   NULL    7
0008    123.4   NULL    8
```

Also, how I can do this on an 'Update' Query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ID to your table ( for example as IDENTITY(1,1)) and use it instead of rowNumber in your query.
Make it as a clustered index and a primary key to maximize performance.